# SQL Query to select duplicates without grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find rows in my table where both power and price match some other row in the table.

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | Power | Price | Name   |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 1  | 300W  | $5.00 | Alpha  |
| 2  | 500W  | $4.00 | Kilo   |
| 3  | 500W  | $3.00 | Whiskey|
| 4  | 300W  | $5.00 | Charlie|
| 5  | 400W  | $4.00 | Oscar  |
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

I want the resulting table to include all columns, including the primary key, and I don't want them grouped.

```
+----+-------+-------+--------+
| id | Power | Price | Name   |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 1  | 300W  | $5.00 | Alpha  |
| 4  | 300W  | $5.00 | Charlie|
+----+-------+-------+--------+
```

What can I do to find duplicates without any of the columns or duplicate rows being eliminated?

Comment: Do a self join.

Comment: Please, provide the query used for the current result

Comment: @reisdev I don't know what the query is. That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you question!

Answer (score 3):

If your RDBMS support window functions, you can use function `COUNT()`, then select only the records having count higher than 1 :

```
select id, Power, Price, Name
from (
  select *, count(*) over (partition by Power, Price) as cnt
  from mytable
) as s
where cnt > 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/FDKGegcH)

Answer (score 2):

Basic doubloon search :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM mytable t2
    WHERE t1.id <> t2.id
    AND t1.Power = t2.Power
    AND t1.Price = t2.Price
);
```